# Filter duplicated based on values of another column

Tags: linux, filter, duplicate

I have the following example of a dataframe.Where you see that elements of 3nd column could be duplicated.I want to keep the entry which has the highest value in column 5

Meaning that  for **AGCCCGGGG** I want to keep the second entry which the 5th column has the value of 49.

```
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1124:7120:12352  ATCAGCCCGGGGCTTGGGCTAGGAC   GGGTGTGTG   548476  0   Corynebacterium
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1150:15953:12524 CCTATCGTCGCTGGAATTCCCCGGG   AGCCCGGGG   1458266 1   Bordetella
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1150:15628:12743 CCTATCGTCGCTGGAATTCCCCGGG   AGCCCGGGG   1458266 49  Bordetella
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1450:4001:4507   GGCGATCGAAATGTCAAGCCCGGGG   TCTTGTGGT   585529  0   Corynebacterium
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:2124:8865:2472   ATCAGCCCGGGGCTTGGGCTAGGAC   GGGTGTGTG   548476  0   Corynebacterium
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:2476:4001:29496  ATTCACCCTATAGGAGCCCGGGGCA   TGCCCCGGG   1458266 0   Bordetella
```

Comment: Does your data use spaces or tabs as separators? Are all columns always present? May the data be resorted? How to handle if the number in `$5` appears multiple times for equal `$3`?

Comment: yes it's tab separated and all columns are always present. If the number in $5 appears multiple times select randomly.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is useful tool here:

```
awk -F'\t' 'l[$3] {if ($5>n[$3]) {n[$3]=$5; l[$3]=$0} ; next} 
            {n[$3]=$5 ; l[$3]=$0}
            END { for (i in l) {print l[i]}}' infile
```

`-F'\t'` - use tabs as field separators

Let's start with the second line: `n[$3]=$5` stores the number in column 5 in an array `n` indexed by column 3 and the wole line in an array `l` by the same index. However, this will only happen at the first occurence of a unique value in colunm 3, since with:

`l[$3] {...}` commands in braces are only executed if an element in array `l` with index `$3` (=column 3) is present. In this case compare the stored value in `n` to column 5 and update if need be. `next` means *skip to the next record*, i.e. line of the file.

`END` - loops thorugh array `l` and returns all lines with unique `$3` and (first) highest value in `$5`. Sorting of original file is `**not** maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sort and any awk:

```
$ sort -rnk5,5 file | awk '!seen[$3]++'
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1150:15628:12743 CCTATCGTCGCTGGAATTCCCCGGG       AGCCCGGGG       1458266 49      Bordetella
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:2476:4001:29496  ATTCACCCTATAGGAGCCCGGGGCA       TGCCCCGGG       1458266 0       Bordetella
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:2124:8865:2472   ATCAGCCCGGGGCTTGGGCTAGGAC       GGGTGTGTG       548476  0       Corynebacterium
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1450:4001:4507   GGCGATCGAAATGTCAAGCCCGGGG       TCTTGTGGT       585529  0       Corynebacterium
```

or using any awk on it's own:

```
$ awk '
    !($3 in max) || ($5 > max[$3]) { max[$3]=$5; line[$3]=$0 }
    END { for (key in max) print line[key] }
' file
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:2476:4001:29496  ATTCACCCTATAGGAGCCCGGGGCA       TGCCCCGGG       1458266 0       Bordetella
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1150:15628:12743 CCTATCGTCGCTGGAATTCCCCGGG       AGCCCGGGG       1458266 49      Bordetella
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:2124:8865:2472   ATCAGCCCGGGGCTTGGGCTAGGAC       GGGTGTGTG       548476  0       Corynebacterium
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1450:4001:4507   GGCGATCGAAATGTCAAGCCCGGGG       TCTTGTGGT       585529  0       Corynebacterium
```

We use `!($3 in max)` to initialize `max[$3]` the first time `$3` is set rather than based on any `$5` value so it will work even if the max value was 0 or negative. The rule of thumb for min/max calculations is to always initialize using the first value read, not 0 or any other arbitrary value.

We don't need so set FS to a tab since you said all fields are always present and best I can tell there can never be a blank in any of the first 5 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sort`:

```
sort -k3,3 -k5,5nr /tmp/my_acgt_file | sort -k3,3 -u
```

Left-hand side sorts your file on the 3rd field (lowest first) and then, in case of equality, on the 5th field (highest first).

Right-hand side only considers the (already sorted) 3rd field and guaranties it will be unique by keeping the first it meets and discarding the others.